# Phase Transition in Graphene, classical or quantum approach?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phase-transition

Graphene is a high quality 2D crystal, which is stable at room temperature is amazing because in the 1930's Landau and Peierls showed that thermodynamics prevented 2D crystals from existing in free state. The melting temperature of thin films decreases rapidly with temperature as a result monolayers are generally unstable.

"Obtaining Graphene (2D) from Graphite (3D) using a scotch tape as done by Prof. Geim and Novoselov in 2004, is it a **Phase Transition**? Can the classical **Landau Theory of Phase Transition** be applied? If so, what could be the **Order Parameter**? Thanks

Comment: Phase transitions in a statistical-mechanics sense consider situations where slow variation in a thermodynamic variable leads to abrupt change in a system. When you make graphene, the application of scotch tape is already an abrupt change in the system, and therefore is not covered by the statistical-mechanics definition.

Comment: @probably_someone we can consider a system consisting of $n$ layers of carbon and, at least theoretically (although it is not particularly outlandish to do experimentally), consider slowly varying $n$ in exactly the way you describe and examining the properties of the resulting material. Now it may turn out that at small $n$ you get qualitatively different results for each $n$, before setting into something graphite like, and so viewing it in a phase transition paradigm is not terribly constructive (i.e. the transition is effectively at $n=1$), but that is certainly not obviously the case.